# What would be the best way to compare specific words in a string against an if or while statement in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a McDonalds Menu as a side project and having trouble with comparing string characters against what the user inputs. I want to be able to display a specific menu based on user response and being able to display the correct menu based on user response, and right now it doesn't display the menu even though I'm calling the function that is going to do that. Is there something wrong with the placement of my if statement? Right now I'm just testing one menu type but I have also tried to work with multiple but I'll start with this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getMenu(string menuType);
void breakfastMenu();
void lunchMenu();
float calculateSubTotal();
float calculateTotal();

void getMenu(string menuType)
{
   cout << "Which menu would you like to order from today?\n" << end;
   getline(cin, menuType);
}

void breakfastMenu()
{
    cout << "#1 Egg McMuffin Meal" << endl; 
}

void lunchMenu()
{
    cout << "#1 Big Mac Meal" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    string menuType;

    cout << "Welcome to McDonalds, how may we help you today? " << endl << endl;

    getMenu(menuType);

    if(menuType == "breakfast")
    {
        breakfastMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing by value the string so the original will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the string `MenuType` by value so inside the function `GetMenu` you are inputting a local temporary variable so the original will not be changed.

To correct it pass by reference or by pointer:

Change the signature of GetMenu to:

```
 void getMenu(string&); // the protoype

 // and the function
 void getMenu(string& menuType){

 }
```

- An alternative to you function GetMenu is to make it return  the choice as string not just void:

  ```
  std::string getMenu(){
      std::string strChoice;
      std::getline(std::cin, strChoice);
      return strChoice;
  }
  ```

  And in main:

  ```
  std::string menuType = getMenu(); // Now it looks logical
  ```

Comment: `std::string getMenu()` would perhaps be better.

Comment: @KenY-N Yes that is it. You are perfectly righteous. But I just explained the to OP his mistake. Now I made to return a string instead.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys I'm not super good at programming right now so this is why I'm trying to do a side project thanks for the great help to start me off, and I will probably read more about passing by reference and value because I still get mixed up on those.